# Nuget downgrade warning in xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget

I have a big problem with installation of NuGet package. When I try to compile my code, I get this error:

> Error NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Xam.Plugin.Geolocator from 100.0.0 to 4.5.0.6. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
>    MyProject -> xxx -> xxx -> Xam.Plugin.Geolocator (>= 100.0.0) 
>    MyProject  -> xxx (>= 4.5.0.6)

I am then trying to install a different version of this package but I end up with the same error. How I can fix this problem? This package is not visible as installed in NuGet.

Comment: Update the packages manually

Comment: What is the name and version of the package you are trying to install? Can you reproduce the issue with a fresh blank project? Did you clean your solution? Which different version of the package are you trying to install? Do you get *exactly* the same error? What do you mean `This package is not visible as installed in NuGet.`?

Comment: @Tiger According to your error message, you project is Xamarin.Forms? You install different version Xam.Plugin.Geolocator for Forms and platform? Please confirm it.